# The datetime type is not retained when the query result is saved as csv

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the following query to fetch some results from a **bigquery** dataset:

```
SELECT name, TIMESTAMP(due) AS due, TIMESTAMP(start) AS start,
FROM myBigQueryTable
```

Then, I save the query result as csv. However, the due and start columns do not have datetime type in the csv file and displays a value like:

```
1.41E+09
```

instead of this:

```
2014-12-24 00:00:00 UTC
```

If I only use `DATE` instead of `TIMESTAMP` then the problem disappears, however I also need the time info. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with BigQuery UI and it is tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36614760.
I have the fix ready and it will go out into production within few weeks.